# Necessary rights to be able to add a column with ALTER TABLE ADD column_name

Tags: sql-server-2005

Could somebody point out the necessary rights to do something like

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD myColumn int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [Constraint_name] DEFAULT ((0))
```

?

I assumed

```
grant alter on myTable to [user]
```

was enough but I'm getting the error message

```
The UPDATE permission was denied on the object 'myTable', database 'x', schema 'dbo'.
```

Could UPDATE rights be needed because of the DEFAULT constraint?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to grant the update right. Since you have the `not null` constraint and the default value, every row needs to be updated with `0`.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was thinking but I couldn't check due to lack of rights :).